# SqlServer import export Wizard - Set destination to Windows Authentication

Tags: sql-server, import, export, windows-authentication

i couldn't fine the connection string to set to windows authentication to carry out my import operation.. help me to set connection string, i know how to set the connection for sql server ,but not using windows authentication

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like your trying to use the .Net Framework Data Provider for ODBC as your data source.

Instead change the data source to SQL Server Native Client. Then you will have the option to use Windows Authentication rather than trying to create an exact connection string.

[image]